# how to get consumer key for OAuth when working from locahhost

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, calendar

Im trying to integrate google calendar in my php application. I managed to do actions like inserting events using zend framework. But when coming to the authentication and authorization, I chose first the Client Login method but I read after that this solution was impossible with web browser application.So I'm going to use Zend-OAuth. Here is the link http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html. To do such authentication, secret key and consumer key are required. My problem is that I register the app using https://code.google.com/apis/console but all what I got is secret key, client ID and API key . I don't know how to get a consumer key.
Also, callback URL and site URL are required and I don't know how to set these values when working from localhost.

Could anyone help me please ? I am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google Client ID is your Consumer Key, the Client Secret is your Secret Key. If you are using localhost, then just put in localhost as the site URL. It will default the Callback URL to `https://localhost/oauth2callback`. You can change the callback URL (or add additional Site URLs by clicking the MORE OPTIONS link).

Comment: And do I have to set a value for CallbackURL?

Comment: If you don't specify one, then it will default to `https://localhost/oauth2callback`.